# Is there a definite answer for the performance of 1st level depth query search in Neo4j (or any other graph db) vs. SQL/NoSQL?

Tags: neo4j

I am testing the use of Neo4j for social-like graph, but I also have many use-cases that require 1st level depth queries (e.g. get my likes / views). Consequently, I wish to decide whether I need another SQL/NoSQL to support (in terms of performance) this type of queries.
Up until now, I was only able to find benchmarks and quantitive data concerning > 1st level searches (i.e. friends of my friends ...)
Is it common knowledge that SQL/NoSQL db will have better performance for such queries? are there any research/benchmarks about this?

Answer (score 0):

A depth of 1 shouldn't result in much difference in performance, I'd think. However, that does depend on two factors: the indexes you've set up, and the depth of expansion.

For both Neo4j and your relational db, you would want a supporting index on the starting node in the graph (the person or post whose likes/views you want to get). For the relational db, you would also want an index to support the join operation being used to get at the connected nodes.

For Neo4j, the expansion to the connected nodes is directly proportional to the number of nodes you are expanding to, since this is just pointer chasing between the nodes and relationships forming your graph. No indexes are used for that.

For a relational database, the relationship would likely be modeled as a table join (which should be index-backed), and that cost will be proportional to the size of the tables being joined, so as more data is added to the graph (no matter of whether it is connected to the user who you are querying for), it will be impacting your execution time.

Thankfully for your case only a single table join would be needed. You may not see a big difference between a graph db and a relational db. Neo4j tends to shine when many (possibly an unbounded number) of traversals are needed, like the friend-of-a-friend queries or those with longer patterns. If your use cases include longer patterns, especially if the types of the node expanded to are not known ahead of time, then Neo4j would be very helpful, especially as the data in your database grows, since traversal performance is proportional only to the directly connected data, not the total number of nodes of the given labels.